# UIButton in UICollectionViewHeader doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

EDIT: The code works in the body of the cell, but not in the header!

I have added a button programmatically to my view. Everything is properly displayed. When I press the button it is highlighted.
The problem is that the function is not called. Does anybody has an idea to solve the problem?

```
let addPerson : UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton(type: .system)
    btn.setTitle("Test button", for: .normal)
    btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    btn.backgroundColor = .darkGray
    btn.layer.masksToBounds = true
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleAddPerson), for: .touchUpInside)
    btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return btn
}()

@objc func handleAddPerson() {
    print("test")
}


//Following is inside the init
let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [addPerson,addGroup])
    stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.spacing = 10
    addSubview(stackView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 8),
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -8),
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 8),
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -8),
        ])
```

Comment: How do you add it ?

Comment: There are two buttons inside a stackView. The stackView is inside a CollectionViewCell

Comment: Verify that you set constraints properly or  upload a demo ?

Comment: The constraints are properly set. I have to add that the cell is used as the header of another cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to changes the selector to this mate:

```
@objc func handleAddPerson(_ sender: UIButton?) {
    print("test")
}
```

Comment: That's weird. Btw, what's `addGroup`. Is there any chance there's a mismatch between these.

Comment: There is no mismatch. The code works in the body of the cell, but when I change it to the header it no longer works